# Solaris svcs command shows wrong status

Tags: solaris, hyperic

I have freshly installed an application on solaris 5.10 .  When checked through `ps -ef | grep hyperic | grep agent`, process are up and running  . When checked the status through `svcs hyperic-agent` command, the output shows that the agent is in maintenance mode . Application is working fine and I dont have any issues with the application . Please help

Comment: Maybe your starter doesn't exit with zero (`SMF_EXIT_OK`) status? Please check logs for service (their location is available from `svcs -x hyperic-agent` component).

Comment: Thanks a million for your reply !!!!!!!      Please find the log snippet.. Oracle Corporation SunOS 5.10 Generic Patch January 2005
-n Starting HQ Agent...
-n .
-n .
-n .
running (3314).
Oracle Corporation      SunOS 5.10      Generic Patch   January 2005
3671
[ Apr 14 10:18:01 Method "start" exited with status 0 ] ...  ..Start method exited with zero .

Comment: Well, there are many ways SMF monitors application: forking and exiting processes, delivered signals, probably one of that bad event had been noticed and SMF marked it as maintenance. These events should be masked in app manifest.

Comment: The actual system that provides SMF such facilities is System Contracts. You may try to `clear` your application status, carefully restart it, and issue `svcs -v hyperic-agent` to get CTID (contract-id) of your service than run `ctwatch CTID` to track that events (if service isn't already marked as maintenance)

Comment: I greatly appreciate the response . After a clear and careful restart, hurrah !! I got the CTID .. Please find the o/p .. But after some time the status is again going into maintenance state ..                                                                        root@rhmwsoss:/opt/hyperic-agent/agent-4.6.6.1-EE/bundles/agent-4.6.6.1/bin# ctwatch 37211
CTID    EVID    CRIT ACK CTTYPE   SUMMARY
37211   28052   crit no  process  contract empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several reasons that lead to that behavior:

- Starter (`start/exec` property of service) returned status that is different from `SMF_EXIT_OK` (zero). Than you may check logs:

  ```
   # svcs -x ssh
   ...
   See: /var/svc/log/network-ssh:default.log
  ```

  If you check logs, you may see following messages that means, starter script failed or incorrectly written:

  ```
   [ Aug 11 18:40:30 Method "start" exited with status 96 ]
  ```
- Another reason for such behavior is that service faults during while its working (i.e. one of processes coredumps or receives kill signal or all processes exits) as described here: https://blogs.oracle.com/lianep/entry/smf_5_fault_retry_models

  The actual system that provides SMF facilities for monitoring that is System Contracts. You may determine contract ID of *online* service with `svcs -v` (field CTID):

  ```
  # svcs -vp svc:/network/smtp:sendmail
  STATE          NSTATE        STIME    CTID   FMRI
  online         -             Apr_14       68 svc:/network/smtp:sendmail
              Apr_14       1679 sendmail
              Apr_14       1681 sendmail
  ```

  Than watch events with `ctwatch`:

  ```
  # ctwatch 68
  CTID    EVID    CRIT ACK CTTYPE   SUMMARY
  68      28      crit no  process  contract empty
  ```

  Than there are two options to handle that:

  - There is a real problem with service so it eventually faults. Than debug the application.
  - It is normal behavior of service, so you should edit and re-import your service manifest, to make SMF less paranoid. I.e. configure `ignore_error` and `duration` properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info !!! it really helped me .. For my case the start method is exiting with zero but I see some error statements in the logs , that I am trying to fix it up . Anyway thanks again !!!!!